# Switching between terminal and vim for a touch-typist

Tags: terminal

I recently got into touch-typing as I thought it might help me in my work and increase my productivity (I am currently a programmer, sometimes editing text files). Oftentimes I find myself switching from vim to terminal to run a command or open a different file.

I was wondering, how do you guys get around having to move your hands all over the keyboard when pressing arrow keys to get commands in terminal from history (what I usually do is edit some file with vim, compile, run, if it does not work I go back into vim editing, then save/close and arrow key up to get the compile and run commands from history). The only problem with this is I cannot keep my hands on the home row (obviously because I have to move to arrow keys).

How do touch-typists get around this? Is there some trick I might be missing?

P.S.: If there is any tool that might allow me to never leave vim, or other tools that you think might help me, please let me know.

P.S.S.: The shell I'm currently using is zsh.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Thank you!!! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Shortcuts from shell

you don't "have to" use the arrow keys to use the history in shells like `zsh`.

- `<c-p>` previous history command.
- `<c-n>` next history command.
- `<c-r>` history search.

or you can add some improvements:

- use [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) instead of regular history search.
- change `fzf` shortcuts.
- change `zsh` shortcuts if necessary (I only added `<c-t>` and `<c-s>` to move one word back and forth, because I don't like to switch between `Alt` and `Ctrl` keys, and I almost never need `transpose-chars`).
- run `bindkey -v` in `zsh` to get vim-like shortcuts.

be aware that I also "cheat" a lot to make arrow keys easier to use:

- I use a special keyboard named [Ergodox EZ](https://ergodox-ez.com/), it's splitted, ortholinear, ergonomic, programmable, with several keys on each thumb. And with this keyboard, I can easily press `<Up>`, `<Down>`, `<Esc>`, `Super` (window key) and `e` with my left thumb, `<Left>`, `<Right>`, `<Return>`, `Ctrl` and obviously `<Space>` with the right thumb, so I don't really have problems with using arrow keys a few times.
- I have my own keyboard layout, with 8 levels instead of 4 (I can press `Shift`, `Altgr` and the right control key to access them), and I have some other arrow keys on `level5`. I can also lock (with `ISO_Level5_Lock`) this level if I need to press arrow keys only for a few minutes.
- I use `TMUX`, with shortcuts to go to another pane or to redo the last command on the next pane while I stay where I am.
- With `vim`, `:!` can be used to do a shell command.
- With `neovim`, there is a `terminal` mode.

Comment: Love my ergodox :)

Comment: PS `transpose-chars` from emacs bindings is basically `xp` in normal mode for vi-bindings :)

Comment: I clicked the link and checked out the Ergodox. I gotta admit that my first thought was "that looks pretty douchey" (sorry, LOL) but I came away pretty impressed with all the functionality it seems to have.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the existing answer:

For shell specifically:

- I use vi keys in bash (`set -o vi`) and zsh (`bindkey -v` with some extra goodies), so I don’t touch arrows that much (Escape + jk works)
- Also, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> reverse incremental search is good
- Heavy use of tmux, with more vi-like bindings

For vim:

- Easy mapping to run `:suspend`
- Easy mapping to run `:terminal` (actually, for some languages it starts a repl, based on my config, but it defaults to a shell otherwise; see [vim-simpl](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-simpl))
- With tmux, I can easily open a new shell anywhere that’s not tied to vim, so I have lots of options.

So the short answer is—I certainly leave vim (it’s not an Emacs that you have to be in 24/7), but I prefer to make everything else feel a bit like vim (because my fingers live for vim keys now).

Comment: And the default binding to `:suspend` is `CTRL-Z`.

Comment: yeah, that can be a bit awkward to type on my ergodox @Quasímodo, but good point!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use full Vim power for terminal commands.

Just enter:

```
q:
```

and split pane opens where one can enter terminal commands prepending them with `!` (press enter to execute). It's Vim, so navigation, editing, searching etc working as expected (this is actually history of `:` commands)

I mainly use Python (no compilation needed) so I tend to have this workflow:

- write code in `.py` file
- run current file using

  ```
  :!clear && python3 %
  ```
- observe result
- hit return and be back in current file

Next time I need to run file I enter:

```
q:kk<enter>
```

where `kk` denotes navigation a couple of rows up in history depending how many `:` commands have been issued between different runs of file (to reach the command I gave earlier to run file).

If I am sure that there has been none then I would do repeat last command with:

```
:!!
```

Making adjustments/editing the commands in history is very easy as this is 'full' Vim. Fore example search for command in history with <kbd>/</kbd>, navigate with <kbd>n</kbd> between matches, make edits in normal mode or insert additional text in insert mode on suitable row and press enter.

As for terminal, additionally to suggested vi keybindings I have added visual clues to distinguish between different modes.

On MacOS I added these rows to my `.bashrc`:

```
# set vi navigation and jj as switch to normal
set -o vi
bind '"jj":vi-movement-mode'
```

And to display `+` (insert mode) or `:` (normal mode) at the beginning of the prompt I added following to `.inputrc`:

```
set editing-mode vi
set show-mode-in-prompt on
set vi-ins-mode-string \1\e[6 q\2 +
set vi-cmd-mode-string \1\e[2 q\2 :
```

My prompt is very minimalistic, one of below, depending of the mode I am in:

```
: >
+ >
```